# How to make self destroying tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, video

I want to play a mp4 video for a few seconds in tkinter window, but for closing windows i need to click in close button. i want, after playing the video it will self close the windows.

This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk, threading
import imageio
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

video_name = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\CA SOFTWARES\\CA\\boot.mp4" 
video = imageio.get_reader(video_name)

def stream(label):

    for image in video.iter_data():
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
        label.config(image=frame_image)
        label.image = frame_image

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    my_label = tk.Label(root)
    my_label.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(my_label,))
    thread.daemon = 1
    thread.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

The above code to play a mp4 video, i want after playing this video it will close automatically without clicking on close button.

Comment: Your program will play the video at a frame rate that's entirely dependent on the performance of the computer, which is likely not what you or the author of the video wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `root.destroy()` after that loop to close the window.

```
def stream(label):
    for image in video.iter_data():
        # ...
    root.destroy()
```

Comment: No, I can't, sorry. This is literally an one-line addition after the single loop you currently have in your code.

Comment: Giving Me error : File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CA SOFTWARES\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Comment: That smells like tkinter doesn't like the frame being destroyed from another thread. Then you can try `sys.exit()` instead of `root.destroy()`.

Comment: sys.exit() is frizzing the video, video is stucked. if i use root.destroy() it's give me error and if i use sys.exit() it frizzes the video.